# Type casting involving bit-vector operations

Tags: c, casting

Here's my code:

```
uint8_t data[3] = {u >> 16, u >> 8, u & 0xff };
```

`u` is originally a `uint32_t`.

How can I cast the right hand side to be uint8_t? I've tried writing `(uint8_t)(u >> 16)`, but then I get a complaint that `u>>16` doesn't fit the range of `uint8_t`.

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast each element to `uint8_t`:

```
uint8_t data[3] = {(uint8_t)(u >> 16), (uint8_t)(u >> 8), (uint8_t)(u & 0xff) };
```

Comment: I've tried that but then I get a complaint that `u>>16` doesn't fit the range of `uint8_t` (sorry, there was a typo in the original question)

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: I'm writing this in Visual Studio Professional 2012

Comment: Though am running a verification software on the code, which is giving the error, so the problem is probably in the software rather than in the compiler, seeing as the code you suggested is what I'd written. Thanks for your help!